# Using requireJS with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I am following a tutorial about how to use AngularJS with RequireJs. I don't seem to understand how this works.

The author creates a file app.js and inside the file adds;

```
define(function (require) {
    'use strict';

    var angular = require('angular');
    var services = require('./services/services');
    var controllers = require('./controllers/controllers');
    var directives = require('./directives/directives');
    var app = angular.module('App', ['services', 'controllers', 'directives']);
    app.init = function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['App']);
    };
...
})
```

But does not show how the files services.js, controllers.js, and directives.js are structured.

For example in the services file I assume I would have multiple definitions of services. This is a nice structure because it means I can create multiple services or controllers in a single script. The problem I have is to get the services from; var = services into the App.

Comment: based on the naming conventions, i would assume they're folders and he's using the require-all plugin to require entire folders

Comment: How are the files fed into AngulaJs then? Does angular accept multiple entry, notice: var app = angular.module('App', ['services', 'controllers', 'directives']); That would mean 'services' has multiple modules, is this acceptable?

Comment: require() used for services, controllers, and etc, will to register on angular without need of return variables. But there are some problems... the correct sequence of calling .js for services, by example, need to be defined on require.js main file

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo I don't understand. So for example: var services = require('./services/services'); will look in the folder services/services and inlcude all the files? I don't understand how var app = angular.module('App', ['services', 'controllers', 'directives']); is able to pick up the contents of 'var services = ...' and what is in the services variable. I think I don't understand how require() has been used at this point.

Comment: requirejs doesn't will do this... your require('services') only will try to find a file adding '.js' at the end: "yourpath/services.js"... and after load, will to return any exported vars to your variable...

Comment: if you need to import all files at 'services' call, you need to configure the dependences at main file. Look at http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config

Comment: You should to use my personal method... configure require file by file, starting only with angular requirement... You can look at navigator console how the .js files is loading after each config change

Comment: How should the services file look like if it has multiple services. I assume the file will contain a lot of define ([], function (){}). Each define will contain a service is that right? At this point is angularJS able to see all the defined services? Can I have an example of services.js if it has multiple services.

Comment: The following article will help you for implementation. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1039826/Angularjs-Lazy-loading-with-Requirejs-and-OcLazylo

Answer (score 0):

Nesting or grouping files with require is quite common - so the services/services.js file (which is being required in your app above) could look like:

```
define(function (require) {
  var services = {};
  services.service1 = require('services/service1');
  services.service2 = require('services/service2');
  services.service3 = require('services/service3');
  services.service4 = require('services/service4');
  services.service5 = require('services/service5');
  return services;
});
```

and then services.service1 would become available within the app.